# Import AMD/requirejs Javascript file into Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, requirejs, amd

I have a library: js and d.ts files.
How can I import them in es6 typescript file?

**Javascript** file

```
define("Calculator", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Calculator = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Calculator() {
        }
        Calculator.prototype.calc = function (a) {
            return a + 1;
        };
        return Calculator;
    }());
    exports.default = Calculator;
});
```

**d.ts** file

```
declare module "Calculator" {
    export default class Calculator {
        calc(a: number): number;
    }
}
```

**Typescript** file with import:

```
import calculator = require('../libs/calculator');
```

Error says **File '.../libs/calculator.d.ts' is not a module**

Comment: Since it's a named `define` (a bad practice that should be avoided), and the declaration filed correctly reflects that, you need to import it as such: `import calculator = require('Calculator'); `

Comment: @AluanHaddad JavaScript file was generated by tsc.

Comment: That only happens when using the `--outFile` option which shouldn't be applicable in your case

Comment: @AluanHaddad what is recommended option?

Comment: Just compile. Don't use outfile for libraries

Comment: @AluanHaddad I see either `outFile` or `outDir`. I have to put one of them, otherwise no js in output.

Comment: Use `outDir` for libraries. Use `outFile` for applications unless you have another build tool (e.g. [r.js](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js)).